# SQL Function without input parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to create a SQL Function **without** input parameters

Im geting a error for following code

```
create function function_name 
RETURN datetime AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @var datetime
SELECT  @var=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
RETURN @var
END
```

**Error**

```
> 
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
> fx_getcurrent_date, Line 2 Incorrect
> syntax near the keyword 'RETURN'. Msg
> 178, Level 15, State 1, Procedure
> fx_getcurrent_date, Line 7 A RETURN
> statement with a return value cannot
> be used in this context.
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are missing your `()`'s.  Also, it should be `RETURNS` for the first `RETURN`.

```
CREATE FUNCTION function_name
(
) 
RETURNS DATETIME 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @var datetime 
    SELECT @var=CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
    RETURN @var 
END
```

Answer (score 4):

When you create a function, the return type should be declared with `RETURNS`, not `RETURN`.

Answer (score 2):

Its the **()** you are missing after function name and also use **RETURNS** after function name.

Refer this link - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx